# Use code font text in paragraph

Tags: support, status-completed, fonts

String

```
String
```

So let's say this is a question on SO, and I'm asking something about the String class. You'll notice that in the previous sentence "String" has the normal font, I'd like it to have the same font as it would if it were in a code block.

I've seen other posts do this, so I know it's possible.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a backtick (`` ` ``) to achieve this effect.

This `String` is in code font!

Source:

```
This `String` is in code font!
```

*The backtick is below the tilde on my keyboard.*